# Running circuits in a sub-panel

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

Background:
I have an older home with aluminum wiring, all that is working fine and I'm aware of the specifics of using aluminum. However my house doesn't have an adequate number of circuits and the small load center is pretty full. Anything new I want to do in copper and maybe migrate the older aluminum circuits to copper at a letter date. Given this and that the load center is fairly small and a mess with copper and aluminum circuits. I'm adding a new load center next to the existing one that'll be all copper. The feed will be from the side of the existing panel to the side of this new panel and ran up to the top lungs.

Question:
Can I use the center hole / opening of the new box to run all the circuit wires through? Plan is to use 3" pvc conduct straight up and then into the soffit, the conduit would exit in the attic where I'd pull all the indivual wires to J-boxes near the locations where they are needed. Is this against any code or allowed? Can the center "chimney, stack" what ever its referred to be used for this purpose since the main feed is comibg from the side? Any information would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Darin

Comment: Is the new loadcenter mounted to the surface to the wall, or recessed into the wall?

Comment: They are both outside boxes it will be mounted to the surface of the exterior wall right next to the existing load center

Comment: How far is it from the top of the loadcenter to the soffit?

Comment: No more than 4ft probably about 3. Thought was to come out of the box into 3in pvc up to an LB with a piece of 3in going through the soffit and terminating just inside the attic

Comment: Will you be able to get to the cover of the LB without busting stuff up?

Comment: @DarinFennell I'd use a sweep to a bell end instead of the LB to avoid the faff that getting at the LB's cover would be in that space

Comment: Thank you I much appreciate your input. I'm going through all this work I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use that hole to run individual THWN conductors in a complete conduit system to an accessible junction box any where in the attic where you can continue with multiple conduits or cables to other locations. That kind of seems obvious so I suspect you're trying to use 3" PVC as a sleeve that you want to pull NM cables through.

You will be running up against NEC 312.5(C), Chapter 9 conduit fill, and conductor derating 310.15(C)(1). Practically you need to use multiple smaller conduits for 4 cables (up to 9 current carrying conductors), or upsize wire one size for up for 10 to 20 current carrying conductors per conduit, and follow a list of rules.

> 312.5 Cabinets, Cutout Boxes, and Meter Socket Enclosures. Conductors entering enclosures within the scope of this article shall be
> protected from abrasion and shall comply with 312.5(A) through (C).

> (C) Cables. Where cable is used, each cable shall be secured to the
> cabinet, cutout box, or meter socket enclosure.

The NEC defines *panelboard* essentially as the guts of what is typically called a panel or loadcenter, and the metal can it is in is defined as a *cabinet*, so this is about what you are asking. This section applies even to cables entering through a conduit, but gives a detailed exception since there really is no  *Listed* fitting for doing that. (See Article 100 for *definitions*.)

> Exception: Cables with entirely nonmetallic sheaths shall be permitted
> to enter the top of a surface-mounted enclosure through one or more
> nonflexible raceways not less than 450 mm (18 in.) and not more than
> 3.0 m (10 ft) in length, provided all of the following conditions are met:
>
> (1) Each cable is fastened within 300 mm (12 in.), measured along the
> sheath, of the outer end of the raceway
>
> (2) The raceway extends directly above the enclosure and does not
> penetrate a structural ceiling.
>
> (3) A fitting is provided on each end of the raceway to protect the
> cable(s) from abrasion and the fittings remain accessible after
> installation.
>
> (4) The raceway is sealed or plugged at the outer end using approved
> means so as to prevent access to the enclosure through the raceway.
>
> (5) The cable sheath is continuous through the raceway and extends
> into the enclosure beyond the fitting not less than 6 mm (1⁄4 in.).
>
> (6) The raceway is fastened at its outer end and at other points in
> accordance with the applicable article.
>
> (7) Where installed as conduit or tubing, the cable fill does not
> exceed the amount that would be permitted for complete conduit or
> tubing systems by Table 1 of Chapter 9 of this Code and all applicable
> notes thereto. Note 2 to the tables of Chapter 9 does not apply to this
> condition.
>
> Informational Note: See Table 1 in Chapter 9, including
> Note 9, for allowable cable fill in circular raceways. See
> 310.15(C)(1) for required ampacity reductions for multiple
> cables installed  in a common raceway.

Item (2) is possibly problematic for you, but the references in the informational note are the real killers.

Derating, Section 334.80 for NM cable says you can use the 90°C rating from 310.16 for ampacity derating. 5 cables is 10 current carrying conductors, which bumps you up to 50% derating making #10 only good for 20A, #12 good for  only 15A, and #14 good for only 12.5A. So you have to stick to 4 cables or upsize the wire to allow 10 to 20 current carrying conductors.

Ok, so if you then run multiple smaller conduits for 4 cables each you need to calculate the minimum conduit size. The code say to calculate elliptical cables as single round conductors of the major dimension of the ellipse. That's too much math for here, to go Belden's website, it says 12/2 is 0.40", go to their [fill calculator](https://tools.belden.com/conduit-capacity-calculator/), your minimum conduit size for 4@12/2 NM cables is 1.25".

Comment: Quotes from 2020 NEC viewable at https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70 . Copy and paste errors due to ADHD and excessive caffeine may exist that I don't think effect intent of the code.  Any number of mixed cable sizes can change conduit size calculations, each conduit run needs individual consideration.

Comment: Thank you I much appreciate your input. I'm going through all this work I want to make sure I'm doing it right.